# How to access environmental information about a contract from within a chain extension?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, pallet-contracts

When we have an Ink! smart contract code calling a chain extension, how do we receive this information from within the chain extension:

1. The calling smart contract address/ID
2. The original caller of the smart contract (or is this possible?)
3. The equivalent EVM `msg.value` in the smart contract, if there is one?

If there is any tutorial/example that covers the above questions, it will be great just to paste the link out as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about a chain extension?

Comment: Yes, using `#[ink::chain_extension]` and `#[ink(payable)]` as mentioned in [the doc](https://paritytech.github.io/ink-docs/macros-attributes/chain-extension)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These environmental information is available to the `ChainExtension` through the `Environment::ext()` function. An instance of `Environment` is passed to `ChainExtension::call()` as a parameter.

The `ext()` function returns a type that implements [`Ext`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_contracts/chain_extension/trait.Ext.html). Check out the linked documentation for the available functions.

To answer your question:

1. `env.ext().caller()`
2. We don't provide this functionality on purpose because basically every use of this information constitutes a security problem on Ethereum.  We have `env.ext().caller_is_origin()`, though.
3. `env.ext().value_transferred()`

Comment: after some changes,
`env.ext().caller()` is the original caller of the contract.
`env.ext().address()` is the contract address which calls chain extension.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11987